# ensure that logged user have access only to his data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884833/how-to-get-route-data-value) similar question but I'm wondering if solution can be simplified.
As you may already notice I want to ensure that logged user have access ONLY to his data. I'm using custom membership provider in mvc3.

```
[Authorize(Users=httpContext.User.Identity.Name)]
public ActionResult UserArea()
{}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new attribute and override the `AuthorizeCore` method:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContext.User user)
   {
     // Generally authenticated to the site
     if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        return false;
     }

    return true;
   }
}
```

Then on your Controller do:

```
[CustomAuthorize(httpContext.User]
public ActionResult MyControllerAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

http://code.commongroove.com/2012/04/20/asp-net-mvc-simple-custom-authorization-by-inheriting-from-the-authorizeattribute/